# Accessing localhost via a VPN connection

Tags: apache, networking, vpn

### Goal

I am trying to setup a secure connection to a PC in our network.
The goal is to be able to access a domain, `api.mydomain.test`,  on that PC, that is served by `Apache`.

### Setup

To securely connect to the server, I have implemented the Softether VPN Server on the PC. The VPN network must be separate from our own local network, which the PC is also on.

The idea is to add an IP whitelist in the `vhost` record op Apache to allow only people on the VPN subnet to connect to the domain `api.mydomain.test`. Next to this filter, we also added a firewall to the PC to not allow any connection on port `80` or `443`.

### Issue

I can connect to the VPN perfectly and receive an IP ofthe subnet 10.11.12.x.
However, I can't seem to be able to access the server on `localhost` or via the IP of the other network the PC is on (`10.10.2.x`). 
To be frank, I don't even know how to do this when connected to the VPN.

#### What have I tried?

1. Use a local tap bridge instead of virtualNAT and virtual DHCP.

This was not working as expected, because then the VPN clients (my laptop) did not receive an IP.

2. Add `routes` to allow `10.11.12.x` IPs to access `localhost`.

According to documentation of Softether, the virtual NAT does not use the routes, so this would be useless for our goal.

---

What I do not know, is how this is normally setup?

I have the feeling I am trying to do this the wrong way, so any ideas or different approaches would be greatly appreciated!